# SQL Query giving an error of Unknown Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating an application in PHP of Power Meter Analysis. I have following table structure:

table: 'feeds'

```
| feed_id | device_no | current1 | voltage1 | power_factor_1 | vc1 | ic1 | date_added
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 36752   | 2         | 36.048   | 196.01   | 0.9            | 1   | 1   | 2014-06-23 14:14:44
| 36753   | 2         | 35.963   | 195.59   | 0.9            | 1   | 1   | 2014-06-23 14:15:34
```

and so on.

table: 'machine'

```
| machine_id | machine_phone | machine_name | company_id |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2             | ABC Machine  | 1          |
| 2          | 093           | DEF Machine  | 1          |
```

I need records on hourly basis and I have written the following query for this purpose:

```
$sql =  "
            SELECT
                SUM(t.power1) AS 'power1'
                , HOUR(t.date) AS 'pulse_hour' 

            FROM    (
                SELECT
                    IF(@diff = 0, 0, (((f.voltage1*f.vc1)*(f.current1*f.ic1)*(f.power_factor_1))/1000) * (@diff/3600)) AS 'power1'
                    , IF(@diff = 0,0, TIME_TO_SEC(f.date_added) - @diff) AS 'deltaT'
                    , @diff := TIME_TO_SEC(f.date_added)
                    , f.date_added AS 'date'
                FROM
                    feeds f,
                    (SELECT @diff := 0) AS X
                left join
                    machine m
                on
                    f.device_no = m.machine_phone
                left join
                    company c
                on
                    c.company_id = m.company_id
            ";

    $sql .= $params['machine_id'] ? " where f.device_no = '".$params['machine_id']."'" : " where f.device_no > 0";
    $sql .= $params['machine_pulse_datetime_from'] ? " and f.date_added >= '".$params['machine_pulse_datetime_from']."'" : "";
    $sql .= $params['machine_pulse_datetime_to'] ? " and f.date_added <= '".$params['machine_pulse_datetime_to']."'" : "";
    $sql .= $params['company_id'] ? " and c.company_id = '".$params['company_id']."'" : "";

    $sql .= "
                ORDER BY
                    f.date_added ASC
                ) t
            GROUP BY HOUR(t.date)
            ORDER BY HOUR(t.date) ASC

            ";
```

The query is running OK if I remove the following part from the query:

```
left join
                    machine m
                on
                    f.device_no = m.machine_phone
                left join
                    company c
                on
                    c.company_id = m.company_id
```

But with this part It is giving me following error:

```
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'f.device_no' in 'on clause'
```

can you please help me to sort this out... I have spent an hour with this query :(

Comment: You have to join with feeds table which is missing that's why you getting error

Comment: I can't see a cause of the issue as you do seem to have the feeds table in there. However you are using a mix of implicit and explicit joins which is a bit confusing; I would suggest explicitly joining the X sub query (ie, use CROSS JOIN rather than just a comma). Also you appear to be calculating the difference between records, but the select (and thus the calculation) is effectively done before the `ORDER BY f.date_added ASC` clause, hence you results might not be as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your `join`:

```
         FROM feeds f,
              (SELECT @diff := 0) AS X left join
              machine m
              on f.device_no = m.machine_phone left join
              company c
              on c.company_id = m.company_id
```

The problem is that you are mixing explicit and implicit joins.  You can fix this by replacing the comma with `cross join`:

```
        FROM feeds f cross join
              (SELECT @diff := 0) AS X left join
              machine m
              on f.device_no = m.machine_phone left join
              company c
              on c.company_id = m.company_id
```

The issue, which is buried deep in the documentation for `select`, is that `,` is a lot like a `cross join` with the exception of scoping rules -- that is, when the table aliases are recognized.  With a comma, the table aliases are not recognized as you expect.  They are with a `cross join`.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) is the reference:

> `INNER [CROSS] JOIN` and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the
>   absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between
>   the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table
>   is joined to each and every row in the second table).
>
> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of `INNER
>   JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and so on. If you mix comma joins
>   with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of
>   the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.
>   Information about dealing with this problem is given later in this
>   section.

Comment: I just set up and SQL fiddle for this and switching a CROSS JOIN fixes the problem - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a52ae/1